# NextJS - Passing data via property to component for editing

Tags: reactjs, next.js, jsx, react-component

I have a page where it will list all books to the admin. And if admin clicks on the EDIT button of any particular book, my app will display a custom modal where it would display the input boxes with the values in it and lets the admin to edit it.

Minimal example of my **component**:

```
import styles from '../../styles/EditPopup.module.css'

export default function EditPopup({ show, setPopupVisibility, item_data }){  
    const onSaveEdit = () => {
        //TODO
    }

    return (
        <div className={ styles.popup } style={ show ? {} : { display: 'none' } }>
            <input type="text" defaultValue={ item_data.title } />
            <input type="text" defaultValue={ item_data.author } />
            <textarea defaultValue={ item_data.desc}></textarea>

            <button onClick={ () => onSaveEdit() } >SAVE</button>
            <button onClick={ () => setPopupVisibility( false ) }>CANCEL</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Minimal example on my **page** where it list all books with the edit button:

```
const [selected_book, setSelectedBook] = useState({ id: '', title: '', author: '', desc: '' })
const [show_edit_popup, setShowEditPopup] = useState(false)

return (
    <EditPopup 
        show={ show_edit_popup }
        setPopupVisibility={ (visibility) => setShowEditPopup( visibility )  }
        item_data={ selected_book } 
    />

    <div>
        { all_books.map( (item, i) => (      
            <div key={ item.id }>
                Title: {item.title}
                Author: {item.author}
                Desc: {item.desc}

                <a href="#"
                    onClick={ (e) => {
                        e.preventDefault()
                        
                        setSelectedBook( prev => ({ ...prev, id: item.id, title: item.title, author: item.author, desc: item.desc}) )
                        setShowEditPopup( true )
                    } } 
                >EDIT</a>
            </div>
        ))}
    </div>
)
```

The problem is, it is not working properly in the popup. The  for desc will always be empty in the popup. And if I type some new value in any of the inputs and I close the popup and clicks the EDIT button on any other item, the value I entered previously in the inputs will still be there. And secondly am being confused here regarding how to get the new user input. Should I go with the `useRef` or `useState` with `onChange`

I know this is something simple for all of you, but am overthinking I guess.

Comment: You can toggle you popup without display: 'none' like this: 
`{show_edit_popup && <EditPopup />}`

Comment: @Edshav thanks that was helpful. Sorry I thought I thanked you earlier, but my comment seem to have not got submitted. Apologies for the delay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You are not handling states correctly**, So go for it with `useState` and `onChange`. For your inputs set an `onChange` as a callback function that comes from the parent component, pass the `event.target.value` through it, and set them in the state initiated in the parent.
also, minimize your state's declaration by batching them in one state.
***the code could be like this:***

```
import styles from '../../styles/EditPopup.module.css'

export default function EditPopup({ data, handleClosePopUp, onSaveEdit, handleChangeInputs }){  
    return (
        <div className={ styles.popup } style={ data.show ? {} : { display: 'none' } }>
            <input type="text" onChange={e => handleChangeInputs(e.target.value, 'title')} value={ data.title } />
            <input type="text" onChange={e => handleChangeInputs(e.target.value, 'author')} value={ data.author } />
            <textarea onChange={e => handleChangeInputs(e.target.value, 'desc')} value={ data.desc}></textarea>

            <button onClick={onSaveEdit} >SAVE</button>
            <button onClick={handleClosePopUp}>CANCEL</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

and your parent

```
const initialData = { show: false, id: '', title: '', author: '', desc: '' }
const [popUpData, setPopUpData] = useState({...initialData})

const handleChangeInputs = (text, type) => {
   setPopUpData(data => {...data, data[type] = text})
}

const onSaveEdit = () => {
   //do your API call or whatever it updates all_books
}

return (
    <EditPopup 
        handleChangeInputs={handleChangeInputs}
        onSaveEdit={onSaveEdit}
        handleClosePopUp={ () => setPopUpData({...initialData}) }
        data={ popUpData } 
    />

    <div>
        { all_books.map(item) => (      
            <div key={ item.id }>
                Title: {item.title}
                Author: {item.author}
                Desc: {item.desc}

                <a href="#"
                    onClick={ (e) => {
                        e.preventDefault()
                        setPopUpData({ show: true, ...item})
                 
                    } } 
                >EDIT</a>
            </div>
        ))}
    </div>
)
```

Comment: Thank you for the example. Along with what @Edshav shared in comment and with yours, I think I was able to get it resolved.